# Does this method already have a name?

Tags: c++

I have found that sometimes functions have very many parameters.  A great many of these parameters will be optional and sometimes a group of these options often come from a single other object (so you end up doing `foo(Object.GetN(), Object.GetM(), Object.GetK())`).  A common way to deal with it is to create different overloads for different situations that it might be called:

```
foo(int n, int m, int k /*, and on and on*/);
foo(bool b, int m/*, ...*/);
foo(int m, int k/*, ...*/);
foo(Object_t object/*, ...*/);
//...
```

The problem here is that which parameter is which isn't particularly intuitive and you can get quite the surprise when you call a different overload than what you intended.

Recently I had an idea to make it easier to get the function call right and make life easier for myself when dealing with these functions that have many different ways of being called.  This solution doesn't cover every possible necessity out there, but it works quite well for me.

Instead of creating different overloads for everything, I would create 1 function that simply takes a variadic number of parameters and then extract possible parameters for use inside the function.  As for the parameters, I would wrap them in helper classes that would be created for these functions.  This would allow for the user declaring what each integer or boolean or string or what-have-you means instead of relying on positional information within the function's signature.

Instead of `foo(n, m)` (which going by the names of the variables above suggests a likely bug) you would call `foo(OptN(n), OptM(m))` making it completely clear what each parameter is going to be used for and much harder to have a parameter be misinterpreted.

I will include a MCVE at the end if anyone's interested in 1 possible implementation of this.

I have never seen or heard of this technique before, but I also have a hard time believing that I'm the first one to think of it.  So, finally, my question is simply does this technique have a name already?

If it doesn't have a name already, I have been calling these functions 'declarative functions' since you declare what each parameter represents explicitly instead of 'positional functions' relying on where the parameter appears to give it its meaning.

**MCVE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Option1
{
    Option1(bool b):b(b){}
    bool b;
    bool operator()() const {return b;}
};

struct Option2
{
    Option2(int n):n(n){}
    int n;
    int operator()() const {return n;}
};

struct Group : Option1, Option2
{
    Group(bool b, int n):Option1(b), Option2(n){}
};

/*
 * Get the option from what the user gave us.
 */
template <class OptionType, class OptionsGetter, class RType>
auto GetOptionImpl(const OptionsGetter & options_getter,
                   const RType&, std::true_type) ->
    decltype(((const OptionType&)options_getter)())
{
    return ((const OptionType&)options_getter)();
}

/*
 * Get the default value specified since the user didn't pass
 * in that option
 */
template <class OptionType, class OptionsGetter, class RType>
RType GetOptionImpl(const OptionsGetter&, const RType & d, std::false_type)
{
    return d;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of the option OptionType if the user 
 * passed that in (inside OptionsGetter) and returns the
 * default value if they didn't pass it in.
 */
template <class OptionType, class OptionsGetter, class RType>
auto GetOption(const OptionsGetter & oOptionsGetter,
               const RType & oDefault) ->
    decltype(std::declval<OptionType>()())
{
    return GetOptionImpl<OptionType>(oOptionsGetter, oDefault,
                                     std::is_base_of<OptionType, OptionsGetter>());
}

template <class ... Params>
void foo(Params ... params)
{
    struct ParamsGetter : Params...
    {
        ParamsGetter(Params ... p): Params(p)...{}
    } params_getter(params...);

    if(GetOption<Option1>(params_getter, false))
        std::cout << "Option 1 was true ";
    else
        std::cout << "Option 1 was false ";
    std::cout << "Option 2: " << GetOption<Option2>(params_getter, 3) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo(Option1{true}, Option2{22});
    foo();
    foo(Option2{1});
    foo(Group(true, 2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Option 1 was true Option 2: 22
Option 1 was false Option 2: 3
Option 1 was false Option 2: 1
Option 1 was true Option 2: 2
```

Comment: It's not obvious to understand why you needed all that....

Comment: Is this what you're searching for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter

Comment: @jpo38 I admit that my example is completely abstract.  I have found it useful, but am also putting it up here in case someone has a better/cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this concept is called named parameter. See the explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter), as well as for instance this [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) to introduce it in C++.

Comment: Reading the article, it seems in C++ this is called the _named parameter idiom_ and the article describes how this is implemented by chaining methods together.  I guess it's a bit out of date now with C++11's variadic templates

Answer (score 0):

I think this is commonly called an *opaque typedef* or a *strong typedef*. The idea is to solve the exact problem you're describing - you have types that have integral values but you want to make it possible to explicitly set them.

For more motivation on this concept, you can see [this proposal](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3741.pdf) for inclusion in the language and [Boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) of it.

Comment: The `opaque typedef` seems to be a part of the solution, but the named parameters idiom is what seems to help with the optional parameters.

Comment: @GuyGreer Named parameters is literally naming the parameters. That'd be `foo(.a = 7, .b = 4)` (assuming that proposal gets approved) or some other mechanism like `foo().a(7).b(4)`. You're not naming the parameters, you're typing (as in type system) them.

Comment: This is supposedly called the _named parameter idiom_ and consists of emulating the behaviour that other languages support directly.

Comment: @Barry: are you sure? From the question: "Instead of creating different overloads for everything, I would create 1 function that simply takes a variadic number of parameters and then extract possible parameters for use inside the function. "
Also the examples in the main method:
"foo(Option2{1});"
"foo(Option1{true}, Option2{22});"
It seems to me the syntax used is just an ad-hoc way of naming the parameters, in this case.

Comment: @Étienne We're not naming the parameters. We're differentiating them by type.

Comment: FWIW I believe that you are both right. We are differentiating the parameters by type, but the names of those types are chosen to be the names of the parameters. However, further to that this technique allows to pass the parameters in whatever order I choose and omit parameters that I don't need, which is an advantage of the named parameters and of its emulation here. There are other things that are possible here that further move away from this being an opaque typedef.